# margin offset from left begining output text via css style

Tags: html, css

i have only litle overview with css so i ask, i have this form

```
<h:form>
      <h:outputLabel1 value="some text1"/>
      <h:outputText1 value="someOutputtext1 />
       .
       .
      <h:outputLabelN value="some textN"/>
      <h:outputTextN value="someOutputtextN/>
 <h:form/>
```

result is some like this :

some text1      someOutputtext2 
 some textN      someOutputtextN

how set offset margin via style="" attributte from beginning of "some text1" to beginning to "someOutputtext2" i want reach than each output text will have same starting position, Thanks for much any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a h:panelGrid to create the form.
Like this:

```
    <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid id="panel" columns="2">
                    <h:outputLabel value="some text1"/>
                    <h:outputText value="someOutputtext1 />
                    <h:outputLabel value="some textN"/>
                    <h:outputText value="someOutputtextN/>
            </h:panelGrid>
    <h:form/>
```

I recomend you to add a new column of messages to handle validation errors, the tag

```
    <h:outputLabel1>
```

doesn't exist, use

```
    <h:outputLabel >
```

and ad a id attribute to mark a field with a unique name.

Sorry for my bad english